# Using the Microsoft StreamInsight Event Flow Debugger with an In-Process Host

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, complex-event-processing, streaminsight

I'm trying connect to an in-process StreamInsight host running in Visual Studio (as opposed to the windows service version) using the Event Flow Debugger tool, and I have been unsuccessful.

Does anyone have experience with this? I'm looking at the following blog posts:

End to end StreamInsight example: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/masimms/archive/2010/08/10/building-your-first-end-to-end-streaminsight-application.aspx

In-process vs. Standalone Host deployment models: http://seroter.wordpress.com/2010/06/27/leveraging-and-managing-the-streaminsight-standalone-host/

Comment: Hi Dave, I could use Event Flow Debugger but can't start recording. An Error Message "No metadata about this query was found in the server. Refresh the Object Explorer to update the list of running queries or close the connection and open it again." Any idea about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to explicitly open up a WCF management service endpoint for any embedded StreamInsight host. You can choose any URL that you have permission to create. Once you start up your embedded server with the management point host opened, you can connect the Event Flow Debugger to the URL chosen.

For the standalone host, there is an entry in the StreamInsight.exe.config file that holds the management service endpoint URL used by the standalone Windows Service. This host is automatically opened when you start the Windows Service associated with the instance.

Comment: Thanks. I finally found some sample code that accomplishes what I was looking for: WSHttpBinding binding = new WSHttpBinding(SecurityMode.Message);
binding.HostNameComparisonMode = HostNameComparisonMode.Exact;
host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IManagementService),
binding,
“http://localhost:8090/MyStreamInsightServer”);